# Collect tracking code Error: You currently have no identified users. The igo_profiles data extension will only be populated with identified users

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein-recommendations, tracking

I am facing this error and cannot seem to solve the issue.

"You currently have no identified users. The igo_profiles data extension will only be populated with identified users."

With the collect tracking code, most of the users tracked will not be known, what is the correct way to fix this issue to make the users "identified" I am confused on exactly what it wants.

We are trying to get url tracking information for known and unknown users using the tracking code. Product and Content catalogs are uploaded as well.

Any help is greatly appreacted, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Before being able to see records in IGO_PROFILES data extension, you must configure Marketing Cloud Collect Tracking Code to create and maintain a basic user record and add optional subscriber information to a contact profile.

The `setUserInfo` push is an important addition to the call by passing the Contact ID (or any other unique identifier - for privacy reasons, I recommend using a non personally identifiable information (PII) identifier or hashing the email).

No matter what type of ID is chosen, use the email label for this field and add the value in the SetUserInfo snippet. You do not need to add it to every page because adding it once ties the known identifier to the Collect Tracking Code cookie.

```javascript
<script type="text/javascript">
_etmc.push(["setOrgId", "MID"]);
_etmc.push(["setUserInfo", {"email": "INSERT_UNIQUE_ID"}]);
_etmc.push(["trackPageView"]);
</script>
```

Add this call everywhere that a user logs in or becomes known. Some common areas to be watching for include:

- login pages or modals
- signup pages or modals
- login steps, check out process, and so forth
- newsletter signup

1. Copy and customize the script by replacing "INSERT_UNIQUE_ID" with dynamic code to get the Subscriber ID. A Subscriber
   ID is unique to that user.
2. Add the modified script in the header code on your pages.

For testing purposes, you can get the UNIQUE_ID from URL by using following code:

```javascript
<script type="text/javascript">
const params = new Proxy(new URLSearchParams(window.location.search), {
  get: (searchParams, prop) => searchParams.get(prop),
});
// Get the value of "unique_id" in eg "https://example.com/?unique_id=1234"
let unique_id = params.unique_id; // "1234"
_etmc.push(["setOrgId", "MID"]);
if (unique_id) {
_etmc.push(["setUserInfo", {"email": unique_id}]);
}
_etmc.push(["trackPageView"]);
</script>
```

Comment: Is there a good way to "Hardcode" the tracking code for testing purposes before adding dynamic code to get the Subscriber ID? Thank you so much for the answer by the way!

Comment: You can add the ID from the URL, like in my updated example

Comment: @axehank - please remember to mark this answer and my answer to your previous question as accepted, if they have been helpful.